# Get awk result greater than X

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, awk

Command:

```
grep "redirect=on" access_log | awk '{print $1}' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -3
```

Output is:

```
34  3.247.44.149
6   5.218.131.185
3   7.173.135.94
```

**Question:** How to output only where the NR is greater then 10. In this case:

```
34  3.247.44.149
```

I tried already to play with $1 > 10 but $1 is the IP and not the number.

Thank you.

Comment: How about posting the data you want to process instead of already aggregated output?

Comment: grep "redirect=on" access_log

Comment: post a fragment from `access_log`, let's say the first 10 lines. Post `head access_log` output

Comment: I thought access_log looks always the same:  3.247.44.149 - - [06/Jul/2017:11:56:24 +0200] "GET /myurl.html?redirect=on HTTP/1.0" 200 21917 "myreferer.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"

Comment: `awk '{if ($0 >= 10){print $1}}'`?

Comment: @jww I tried it but $0 seems not to be the ResultNumber. Its not working. Output is the same.

Comment: To answer your question _How to output only where the NR is greater then 10_: `awk 'NR>10' file`. If that doesn't answer your question, please edit the question to meet your requirements.

Comment: `NR` is the line number. Is `NR>10` really what you want to output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With single ***awk***:

```
awk -F'[[:space:]]+|?' '$8=="redirect=on"{ a[$1]++ }
     END{ for(ip in a) if(a[ip] > 10) print a[ip],ip }' access_log
```

- `-F'[[:space:]]+|?'` - field separator
- `$8=="redirect=on"` - considering only records with query param `"redirect=on"`
- `a[$1]++` - count same IP address occurrences

Comment: like a charm. Thank you very much Roman - very smart solution :)

Comment: @labu77, you're welcome (I've added some explanations)